# how to center highcharts at the middle

Tags: highcharts

I have two axis in highcharts and I dont specify the range for either.  Please see graph.

[image]

For some reason, series one from 201 to 206 is taking up the whole chart while series 2 which is only -2k to 2k is being squeezed to the bottom, thereby extending the range all the way to 30k which is totally unnecessary.  I think highcharts by nature wants to not have any overlap but I want that.  What I'd like is for the right series to be centered, in fact I want the right axis to be centered at 0 always and can grow unrestricted in either direction.  I can't hardcode any of these since I have no idea what the values could be.  So Series 1 on the left is ok, but I want the value 0 for series 2 to always start at the middle of the chart.  Any way to achieve that?

Comment: update:  I added the following to the right axis min: -4000,
            max: 4000,
            tickInterval: 500,  now it sort of works but with interval 1000, it still gets squeezed a bit and without it's completely off, it's as if the min and max are completely ignored with another axis in play.  Can someone explain?

Comment: Can you provide some code for your chart? or maybe a live demo like jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) as false.

Comment: Sure, but that's what he did. The answer, without the link, is fully valid. The link is a reference.